# MongoDB: Single result when searching array value

Tags: arrays, mongodb, search

I have a document containing a list of keywords which I want to search on, however Mongo only ever returns a single result even though there are many documents which contain the same keyword.

The documents look something like this:

```
{
    _Id: 51192567f5e65101d471c46b
    Name: "Cat",
    KeyWords: ["cat", "animal", "small"]
}
```

I am searching the database in the mongo shell using the following:

```
db.Resources.find({"KeyWords":"cat"})
```

I wanted to get back all documents where the KeyWords array contains cat (there are many), however I just get one document.

Comment: The schema in my example isn't the actual schema I'm working with, if I create a simple schema as above the search works as expected; there must be something in my full schema that's not quite right

Comment: I know it might sound obvious but do all documents in the collection have exactly the same structure?

Answer (score 1):

I have just checked in my local DB, so please review your structure
[image: MongoDB]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies; after much hunting, it turns out there was a piece of code in the program I'm using to load the data that only stores a single occurrence of any keyword, so although all documents appear to have lots of keywords, each keyword will only appear in a single document!! I was looking at the original data which had the keywords repeated between documents before the program stripped them out.

Data load failure!!!